# TypeError: module.exports.v1beta1 is not a constructor ( in firestore, vuejs )

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

There is a problem with using *firestore* in `vuejs`. Is it because of the version difference?

```
TypeError: module.exports.v1beta1 is not a constructor
```

Below is the code inside firestore. ( node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js )

```
_initClientPool() {
        assert(!this._clientInitialized, 'Client pool already initialized');
        const clientPool = new pool_1.ClientPool(MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_CLIENT, () => {
            const client = new module.exports.v1beta1(this._settings);
            logger_1.logger('Firestore', null, 'Initialized Firestore GAPIC Client');
            return client;
        });
        const projectIdProvided = this._referencePath.projectId !== '{{projectId}}';
        if (projectIdProvided) {
            return Promise.resolve(clientPool);
        }
        else {
            return clientPool.run(client => this._detectProjectId(client))
                .then(projectId => {
                this._referencePath =
                    new path_2.ResourcePath(projectId, this._referencePath.databaseId);
                return clientPool;
            });
        }
    }
```

Please tell us if you need more information. thanks

**My environment.**

- vue : 2.9.6
- firebase : ^4.13.1
- firebase-admin : ^6.3.0

Comment: Had any luck with this bug?
I'm stuck on this as well

Comment: Having similar issues now but w/ Netlify Lambda x Firebase Admin x Firestore.